# Inno Setup - How to read an INF file during the Setup

Tags: inno-setup, inf

i need to know how to read a value from INF file [.inf], during the setup. I want the installer to check the version of the program that i am going to update, This program version is not stored in the registry or any other file, is only in the .inf file. Then is a must to get the version from it.

I got your answers, @Tlama and i cannot use a DLL to get version of the software.
This program only save the current version in the INF file.

What i want to do, is to make the installer to check the current versión of the software that i am working with, and display that version in a label text.

The inf information is this:

```
NetVersion=1.1.1.1
PatchVersion=2.0.1
ProductName=SoftwareX
```

I just need the PatchVersion to display after where it says version: #### :

[image]

this is the code i am trying to fix:

```
function GetInfsam: String;
var
  sVersion : String;
Begin
  sVersion := '';
  GetIniString('', 'PatchVersion', 'sVersion', '{app}\Sam.inf');
  Result := sVersion;
end;

Procedure InitializeWizard7();
var
  L2Ver1 : Tlabel;
  L2Ver2 : Tlabel;
Begin
  L2Ver1:=  TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  L2Ver1.Transparent:= True;
  L2Ver1.AutoSize:= False;
  L2Ver1.WordWrap:= True;
  L2Ver1.Font.name:= 'Agency FB';
  L2Ver1.Font.Size:= 12;
  L2Ver1.Font.Color:= clwhite;
  L2Ver1.Caption:= 'Version:';
  L2Ver1.Parent:= WizardForm.SelectdirPage;
  L2Ver1.Left := 5;
  L2Ver1.top := 260;
  L2Ver1.Width := 150;
  L2Ver1.Height := 40;

  L2Ver2:=  TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  L2Ver2.Transparent:= True;
  L2Ver2.AutoSize:= False;
  L2Ver2.WordWrap:= True;
  L2Ver2.Font.name:= 'Agency FB';
  L2Ver2.Font.Size:= 12;
  L2Ver2.Font.Color:= clwhite;
  L2Ver2.Caption:= GetInfsam;
  L2Ver2.Parent:= WizardForm.SelectdirPage;
  L2Ver2.Left := L2Ver1.Width + L2Ver1.Left + 8;
  L2Ver2.top := 260;
  L2Ver2.Width := 100;
  L2Ver2.Height := 40;
End;
```

Please, i need help to fix my code.

Comment: Does the program you're reading this information for have a file version by itself ? If so, then you should rather use functions like [`GetVersionNumbers`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getversionnumbers.htm) or [`GetVersionNumbersString`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getversionnumbersstring.htm) to read this information directly from the file instead of reading it from *.inf file.

Comment: I want the installer to display the current program version in a TMemo form, and add a condicional that if the current version is X.x.x show me a green color in the Tmemo form, and if not show me a red color in the Tmemo form. The text inside the Tmemo Form will be the current versión that is installed, then thats why i need to read the Inf file that is in the destination folder of te installation.

Comment: And that application itself doesn't have the file version inside ? You'll be reading from the INF file probably something like `GetIniString('SomeFile.dll', 'FileVersion', '', 'File.inf')` and my question is, if that `SomeFile.dll` doesn't have the version information in itself. You should really prefer to read this information directly from the binary file instead of *.inf file.

Comment: Any time the software get updated, the change version goes to the inf file, only to the inf file.... in one string (version=xxxx) then i just want to read that inf version and display it in a TMemo form inside de installer...

Comment: Anyway, you are not expanding `{app}` constant when you're passing a value to the `Filename` parameter of your `GetIniString` function call. You can't even use the `{app}` constant at the `InitializeWizard` stage. Are you going to read that INF file from the previous installation location ?

Comment: I want to read it and display it in the Page of select dir...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to read INF file ?

INF files are just sort of INI files with the [`specified syntax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So to work with INF files you need to treat them as ordinary INI files. Assuming you have a INF file like this:

```
[Add.Code]
File.dll=File.dll

[File.dll]
File=http://www.code.com/file.dll
FileVersion=1,0,0,143
```

You can read the [`FileVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#keys) key by using [`GetIniString`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getinistring.htm) this way:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Version: string;
begin
  Version := GetIniString('File.dll', 'FileVersion', '', 'c:\File.inf');
  if Version <> '' then
    MsgBox('File version: ' + Version, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

### Update:

**1. Malformed INF file**

According to your update, if the content of your INF file looks like this:

```
NetVersion=1.1.1.1
PatchVersion=2.0.1
ProductName=SoftwareX
```

then it's not a well formed INF file, but a name value pair text file saved with INF extension. Real INF files must have a valid `[]` section for each key value set, but this section is missing in your file.

**2. GetIniString function cannot be called with empty Section parameter value**

You must not call the [`GetIniString`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getinistring.htm) function with empty `Section` parameter value, because for the internally called [`GetPrivateProfileString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function it means to return all section names for a given file, not value of a specified key. So for instance the following call is invalid, because the first parameter `Section` cannot be empty:

```
GetIniString('', 'KeyName', 'Default', 'c:\File.xxx');
```

**3. How to work with a name value pair text file ?**

You'll just need to work with that file as with a text file. For a key value text file handling would be ideal to use the `TStringList` class, or at least in Delphi. In InnoSetup unfortunately the `TStringList` class doesn't have published properties needed for a key value content manipulation, so you'll need to make your own key value text file parsing function. Here's the one for getting value for a given key. As the key value delimiter is supposed to be the `=` sign. This function returns a key value when succeed to find a `AKeyName` key in a given `AFileName` file or default `ADefault` value when fails:

```
function GetKeyValue(const AKeyName, AFileName, ADefault: string): string;
var  
  I: Integer;
  KeyPos: Integer;
  KeyFull: string;
  FileLines: TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := ADefault;
  if LoadStringsFromFile(AFileName, FileLines) then
  begin
    KeyFull := AKeyName + '=';
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(FileLines) - 1 do
    begin
      FileLines[I] := TrimLeft(FileLines[I]);
      KeyPos := Pos(KeyFull, FileLines[I]);
      if KeyPos > 0 then
      begin
        Result := Copy(FileLines[I], KeyPos + Length(AKeyName) + 1, MaxInt);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

To read a value of the `PatchVersion` key from the `Sam.inf` file expected in the currently selected install path you can use something like this. This script will update the label value whenever your user change the text in the directory edit box and when the directory selection page is going to be displayed:

```
var
  // target version label must be declared globally
  L2Ver2: TLabel;

procedure DirEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  FilePath: string;
begin
  // assign the expected INF file path
  FilePath := AddBackslash(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text) + 'Sam.inf';
  // read the PatchVersion key value, return N/A if not found
  L2Ver2.Caption := GetKeyValue('PatchVersion', FilePath, 'N/A');
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // create the target label as before
  L2Ver2 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  ...
  // bind the DirEditChange method to the directory edit's OnChange event
  WizardForm.DirEdit.OnChange := @DirEditChange;  
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // if the page has been turned to the select directory page, update the
  // label caption by firing the assigned OnChange event method manually
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectDir) then
    DirEditChange(nil);
end;
```

Comment: Mate... the current version after update is allways saved in the inf file... ill try use the inf as a INI file as how i saw in the answers.

Comment: mate the lv is just one var, what i want to do i to get the information from the inf file to display that in one label text. As how i asked in the question. See it properly. and Thanks

Comment: You have used `lv` as a constant string for a default value, that's why I do so. Anyway, do you want to read (refresh) that `PatchVersion` information every time you pass directory selection page (consider that you can go back and forward to get to this page) or just once (just the first time you reach the directory selection page) ?

Comment: I want my installer to read that INF and display in an specific place in one page, if u see my code, thats my intention.

Comment: No, I mean, do you want to read that information only once, only the first time you reach the directory selection page or every time you reach that page (to have it always fresh) ? Also, you're reading this file from the `{app}` path; does it mean you'll also want to read it every time the user changes the target directory in the select directory page ?

Comment: to the first question, i want to read the information any time i go to directory selection page (this is not that important i can change this label text to the welcoma page or a custom page too), and to the second question, yes i want to read that information even if the user change the target directory.

Comment: One question mate, if i want to use the version i get as a conditional to continue the installation for example if the version i expect is 6.6.6.6 and i get 6.2.3.1 (any other)... i want the install to stop the installation

Comment: Good choice 6.6.6.6 :-) Well, to compare version strings you can try the code posted in [`this article`](http://www.lextm.com/2007/08/inno-setup-script-sample-for-version-comparison-2/) and how to stop the installation depends on when you'll read that file.

Comment: for example:
`function NextButtonClick3(PageId: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
    if (PageId = wpSelectDir) and (PatchVersion < ('6.6.6.6')) then 
    begin
        MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:AppCheckError}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
        exit;
    end;
end;`

Comment: Yes, but instead of `...and (PatchVersion < ('6.6.6.6'))` use `...and (CompareVersion(PatchVersion, '6.6.6.6') = -1)`.

Comment: Hi @TLama, i tried but i didnt work :( i hope you can reply me... and Thanks !

Comment: i used the script to compare version from the website posted in here, but i could not use it... if i try to compare any version do not work.

Comment: Hi @Tlama, thanks for everything, i want to know how to compare the version from a txt, by reading the numbers of the first line only. the txt file only have few numbers, can you help me ?

Comment: The `LoadStringsFromFile` function used in the above example reads the file and stores the lines to the passed array. In the `GetKeyValue` function shown here you can get the first line from `FileLines[0]` by which you access the first element (first line) of the array.

Comment: For example in the code you posted, how will i get the numbers from the first line in the text file, and compare it with any number i want ? in here: `FilePath := AddBackslash(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text) + 'Sam.inf';` should be the name of the new txt (Version.txt) i want to compare... and here `L2Ver2.Caption := GetKeyValue('PatchVersion', FilePath, 'N/A');` should not be Patchversion, because i want to read only the first line, and is a number. How can i edit this ?

Comment: Am not sure about how to edit the function `GetKeyValue`

Answer (score 3):

All my INF files have a structure similar to INI files.
If that's your case too I suggest you to open your INF as if it was INI, using (as suggested by TLama)

*in setup functions:*

```
function GetIniInt(const Section, Key: String; const Default, Min, Max: Longint; const Filename: String): Longint;
function GetIniString(const Section, Key, Default, Filename: String): String;
```

*in preprocessor:*

```
str ReadIni(str 1, str 2, str 3, str? 4)
```

**Description** *(from Inno Setup help)*

Reads the value from an INI file. Argument 1 must be the name of the INI file, argument 2 – the name of a section in the INI file, the third argument is the key in the section to read. Last optional argument can be used to provide the default value that will be returned on failure, if it is omitted, an empty string is returned.

Comment: What you are referring is a preprocessor function. OP asked to read a value during setup, so the preprocessor [`ReadIni`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_readini.htm) is not a good suggestion. Better suggest the [`GetIniString`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getinistring.htm) or [`GetIniInt`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getiniint.htm) depending on how the version is stored in the file.

Comment: @TLama: thanks, added the different context (both are acceptable, in my opinion)